# How to give a new location to a button in c#?

Tags: c#, xaml, button, uwp

```
private void Hangman_OnLoaded()
{
    const int btnSize = 25;
    for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++)
    {
        var btn = new Button { Content = (char)i };
        btn.Width = btn.Height = btnSize;
        var margin = btn.Margin;
        margin.Left += btnSize + 100;
        btn.Margin = margin;
        GridMain.Children.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

So, I have this code block and i want to create alphabet with *ASCII*. I have a Grid named *GridMain*. I want to display ***A-Z***. When I debug, I see that buttons are created in one nest. What should I use to display these letters next to each other?

Answer (score 3):

Since these are buttons, that has single character ( atleast based on your question ), The size of the items will always be the same. So i would suggest you to use GridView with DataTemplate to load ASCII Characters as Buttons.

change your `Hangman_OnLoaded` to below.

```
private void Hangman_OnLoaded()
{
    List<char> bindingData = new List<char>();
    for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++)
    {
        bindingData.Add((char)i);
    }
    variableGrid.DataContext = bindingData;
}
```

Below will be your GridView.

```
<GridView x:Name="variableGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding }">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding ''}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing everything in code behind for the usual reasons, that would look more like this:

```
var GridMain = new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.UniformGrid
{
    Name = "GridMain",
    Rows = 10,
    Columns = 10
};
```

If for some reason you really want to use `Grid`, you need to define rows and columns in the `Grid` and set the row and column values on each `Button`.

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="GridMain">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <!--  etc. however many rows -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <!--  etc. however many columns -->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
//  Row zero, column zero
Grid.SetRow(btn, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(btn, 0);
```

Etc.

If this were WPF (it isn't, but maybe somebody doing WPF will click on this some day), your best, simplest solution is to use `UniformGrid` instead of regular `Grid`, and set the correct number of rows and columns on it:

```
<UniformGrid x:Name="GridMain" Rows="10" Columns="10">
</UniformGrid>
```

[`VariableSizedWrapGrid` might be an acceptable UWP substitute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for `UniformGrid` in your case, but I'm on Win7 here and can't test it.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for quick answer! Actually it is UWP and i assume it works for UWP too?

Comment: @M.Kesküll You have to specify what UI framework you're using. Otherwise the question is totally unanswerable. Maybe `VariableSizedWrapGrid` would do the same job as `UniformGrid`. I think the `Grid` solution with explicit `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinitions` should work in UWP though. Give it a shot.